# How to align a button to bottom of screen

Tags: android, button, android-relativelayout, android-framelayout

I have added a Button to my WebView. But I cannot get it to align to bottom of screen. I have given the code below.

```
Button button = new Button(context);
button.setText("Button");
LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
button.setLayoutParams(params1);
webView.addView(button);
```

Does anyone know how to do this.

Comment: Have you tried Gravity bottom ?

Comment: @Pull I didn't find that option anywhere

Comment: can i know y are  u not trying to place that button below the webview? y inside the webview?

Comment: params1.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;

Comment: @Pull There is no option named params1.gravity

Comment: I post an answer, it is only working with linear, tell me if it work for you

Comment: @Pull that didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got the solution. I did `button.setY(screenHeight-button.getHeight());`

Answer (score 1):

For your concern try like this :;

```
Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

        btn1.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
```

UPDATE :: Try some thing like this for the button U need to place at bottom of screen

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
            android:text="3" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @AndroidHacker I do not want to load it from a layout.

Comment: @glo wants to add that button in webview not in linear or relative layout

Comment: @AndroidHacker I do not want to add the button from a layout xml and i found a solution for this

Answer (score 0):

You can try with an LinearLayout and gravity :

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.gravity=Gravity.BOTTOM;
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. It gives the same result. Button is on top.